# How can I harden bash scripts against causing harm when changed in the future?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rm

So, I deleted my home folder (or, more precisely, all files I had write access to). What happened is that I had

```
build="build"
...
rm -rf "${build}/"*
...
<do other things with $build>
```

in a bash script and, after no longer needing `$build`, removing the declaration and all its usages -- but the `rm`. Bash happily expands to `rm -rf /*`. Yea.

I felt stupid, installed the backup, redid the work I lost. Trying to move past the shame.

Now, I wonder: what are techniques to write bash scripts so that such mistakes can't happen, or are at least less likely? For instance, had I written

```
FileUtils.rm_rf("#{build}/*")
```

in a Ruby script, the interpreter would have complained about `build` not being declared, so there the language protects me.

What I have considered in bash, besides corraling `rm` (which, as many answers in related questions mention, is not unproblematic):

1. `rm -rf "./${build}/"*`
   That would have killed my current work (a Git repo) but nothing else.
2. A variant/parameterization of `rm` that requires interaction when acting outside of the current directory. (Could not find any.)
   Similar effect.

Is that it, or are there other ways to write bash scripts that are "robust" in this sense?

Comment: There is no reason to `rm -rf "${build}/*` no matter where the quote marks go.  `rm -rf "${build}`  will do the same thing because of the `f`.

Comment: Static checking with http://shellcheck.net/ is a very solid place to start. There's editor integration available, so you could get a warning from your tools as soon as you remove the definition of something that's still used.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy To add to my shame, I wrote that script in an IDEA-style IDE with BashSupport installed, which _does_ warn in that case. So yes, valid point, but I really needed a hard cancel.

Comment: Gotcha. Be sure to note the caveats in [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). `set -u` isn't nearly as frowned on as `set -e` is, but it still does have its gotchas.

Comment: joke answer: Just put `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` at the top of every shell script and forget about bash ;)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
set -u
```

or

```
set -o nounset
```

This would make the current shell treat expansions of unset variables as an error:

```
$ unset build
$ set -u
$ rm -rf "$build"/*
bash: build: unbound variable
```

`set -u` and `set -o nounset` are [POSIX shell options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).

An *empty* value would *not* trigger an error though.

For that, use

```
$ rm -rf "${build:?Error, variable is empty or unset}"/*
bash: build: Error, variable is empty or unset
```

The expansion of `${variable:?word}` would expand to the value of `variable` unless it's empty or unset.  If it's empty or unset, the `word` would be displayed on standard error and the shell would treat the expansion as an error (the command would not be executed, and if running in a non-interactive shell, this would terminate).  Leaving the `:` out would trigger the error only for an unset value, just like under `set -u`.

`${variable:?word}` is a [POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Neither of these would cause an interactive shell to terminate unless `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`) was also in effect. `${variable:?word}` causes scripts to exit if the variable is empty or unset. `set -u` would cause a script to exit if used together with `set -e`.

---

As for your second question. There is no way to limit `rm` to not work outside of the current directory.

The GNU implementation of `rm` has a `--one-file-system` option that stops it from recursively delete mounted filesystems, but that's as close as I believe we can get without wrapping the `rm` call in a function that actually checks the arguments.

---

As a side note:  `${build}` is exactly equivalent to `$build` unless the expansion occurs as part of a string where the immediately following character is a valid character in a variable name, such as in `"${build}x"`.

Comment: Very good, thanks! 1) Is it `${build:?msg}` or `${build?msg}`? 2) In the context of something like build scripts, I think using a different tool than rm for safer deletion would be fine: we _know_ we don't want to work outside of the current directory, so we make that explicit by using a restricted command. There's no need to make rm safer in general.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, should be with :. I'll correct that typo now and I'll mention its significance later when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: @Raphael Ok, I've added a short sentence about what happens without the `:` (it would trigger the error only for _unset_ variables). I dare not try to write a tool that would cope with deleting files under a specific path exclusively, under all circumstances. Parsing paths and caring/not caring about symbolic links etc. is a bit too fiddly for me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation helps! Regarding the "local rm": I was mostly musing, maybe fishing for a "sure, that's <toolname>" -- but certainly not trying to help-vampire you into writing it! O.O All good, you've helped enough! :)

Comment: That link to parameter expansions is very useful; never saw those before! Can only recommend a visit to any who search-stumble by.

Comment: It may be a good idea to mention other similar parts of unofficial bash strict mode (see http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/ ) (`set -euo pipefail` + `IFS=$'\n\t'`)

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I don't think I will, sorry. I believe that safety measures like these should be used _when needed_. As with everything that makes an environment safe, it will eventually make people more and more careless and dependent on the safety measures. It's better to know what each and every safety measure does and then apply them selectively as needed.

Comment: @Raphael a safer way of using rm is just `rm -rf "$build" && mkdir "$build"`, if `$build` is unset, rm will complain about not being able to access ""

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes -- as long as `$build` is not part of a compound path. (Either way, but that's an answer, not a comment on this answer.)

Comment: `"Tis would make the current shell treat expansions of unset variables as an error:"` -- note that the documentation claims this doesn't apply to `$@` and `$*`.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to suggest normal validation checks using `test`/`[ ]`

You would had been safe if you'd written your script as such:

```
build="build"
...
[ -n "${build}" ] || exit 1
rm -rf "${build}/"*
...
```

---

The `[ -n "${build}" ]` checks that `"${build}"` is a [non-zero length string](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

The `||` is the logical OR operator in bash. It causes another command to be run if the first one failed.

In this way, had `${build}` been empty/undefined/etc. the script would have exited (with a return code of 1, which is a generic error).

This also would have protected you in case you removed all uses `${build}` because `[ -n "" ]` will always be false.

---

The advantage of using `test`/`[  ]` is there are many other more meaningful checks that it can also use.

For example:

```
[ -f FILE ] True if FILE exists and is a regular file.
[ -d FILE ] True if FILE exists and is a directory.
[ -O FILE ] True if FILE exists and is owned by the effective user ID.
```

Comment: Fair, but a tad unwieldy. Am I missing something, or does it do pretty much the same as `${variable:?word}` @Kusalananda proposes?

Comment: @Raphael it works similarly in the case of "does the string have a value" but `test` (i.e. `[`) has many other checks that are relevant, such as `-d` (the argument is a directory), `-f` (the argument is a file), `-O` (the file is owned by the current user) and so-on.

Comment: @Raphael also, validation should be a normal part of any code/scripts. Also note, if you removed all instances of build, would you not have also removed `${build:?word}` along with it? The `${variable:?word}` format doesn't protect you if you remove all instances of the variable.

Comment: 1) I think there's a difference between making sure assumptions hold (files exist, etc) and checking if variables are set (imho job of a compiler/interpreter). If I have to do the latter by hand, there better be ultra-snazzy syntax for it -- which a full-blown `if` isn't. 2) "would you not have also removed ${build:?word} along with it" -- the scenario is that I missed a usage of the variable. Using `${v:?w}` would have protected me from damage. Had I removed all usages, even plain access wouldn't have been harmful, obviously.

Comment: That all said, your answer is a fair and helful response to the general titular question: making sure assumptions hold _is_ important for scripts that stay around. The specific issue in the question body is, imho, better answered by Kusalananda. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your specific case, I've reworked 'deletion' in the past to move files/directories instead (assuming /tmp is on the same partition as your directory):

```
# mktemp -d is also a good, reliable choice
trashdir=/tmp/.trash-$USER/trash-`date`
mkdir -p "$trashdir"
...
mv "${build}"/* "$trashdir"
...
```

Behind the scenes, this moves the toplevel file/dir references from source to the `$trashdir` destination directory structures all on the same partition, and doesn't spend time walking the directory structure and freeing up the per-file disk blocks right then and there.  This produces much faster cleanup while the system is in active use, in exchange for a slightly slower reboot (/tmp is cleaned on reboots).

Alternatively, a cron entry to periodically clean /tmp/.trash-$USER will keep /tmp from filling up, for processes (e.g., builds) that consume a lot of disk space.  If your directory is on a different partition as /tmp, you could create a similar /tmp-like directory on your partition and have cron clean that instead.

Most importantly, though, if you screw up the variables in any way, you can recover the contents before the cleanup happens.

Comment: "This produces much faster cleanup while the system is in active use" -- does it? I'd have thought both are about changing the affected inodes only. It certainly _isn't_ faster if `/tmp` is on another partition (I think it always is for me, at least for scripts that run in user space); then, the trash folder needs to be changed (and won't profit from OS-handling of `/tmp`).

Comment: You could use `mktemp -d` to get that temporary directory without treading on another process's toes (and to correctly honour `$TMPDIR`).

Comment: Added your accurate and helpful notes from both of you, thanks.  I think I originally posted this too quickly without considering the points you brought up.

Answer (score 2):

Use bash paramater substitution to assign defaults when variable are uninitialized, eg:

rm -rf ${variable:-"/nonexistent"}

Answer (score 1):

I always try to start my Bash scripts with a line `#!/bin/bash -ue`.

`-e` means "fail on first uncathed **e**rror";

`-u` means "fail on first usage of **u**ndeclared variable".

Find more details in great article [Use the Unofficial Bash Strict Mode (Unless You Looove Debugging)](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/). Also author recommends using `set -o pipefail; IFS=$'\n\t'` but for my purposes this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The general advice to check whether your variable is set, is a useful tool to prevent this sort of issue. But in this case there was a simpler solution.

There is most likely no need to glob the contents of the `$build` directory in order to delete them but not the actual `$build` directory itself. So if you skipped the extraneous `*` then an unset value would turn into `rm -rf /` which by default most rm implementations in the last decade will refuse to perform (unless you disable this protection with GNU rm's `--no-preserve-root` option).

Skipping the trailing `/` as well would result in `rm ''` which would result in the error message:

```
rm: can't remove '': No such file or directory
```

This works even if your rm command does not implement protection for `/`.

Answer (score -3):

You're thinking in programming language terms, but **bash** is a scripting language :-) So, use a wholly different *instruction* paradigm for a wholly different *language* paradigm.

In this case:

```
rmdir ${build}
```

Since `rmdir` will refuse to remove a non-empty directory, you need to remove the members first. You know what those members are, right? They're probably parameters to your script, or derived from a parameter, so:

```
rm -rf ${build}/${parameter}
rmdir ${build}
```

Now, if you put some other files or directories in there like a temp file or something that you shouldn't've, the `rmdir` will throw an error. Handle it properly, then:

```
rmdir ${build} || build_dir_not_empty "${build}"
```

This way of thinking has served me well because... yep, been there, done that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is completely off the mark. The assumption "you know what those members are" is incorrect; think of compiler output. `make clean` will use some wildcards (unless a very diligent compiler creates a list of every file it creates). Also, it seems to me that having `rm -rf ${build}/${parameter}` only moves the issue downward a bit.

Comment: Hm. Look how that reads. "Thank you, but this is _for something I didn't disclose in the original question_ so I'm going to not only reject your answer but downvote it, despite it being more applicable to the general case." Wow.

Comment: "Let me make additional assumptions beyond what you wrote in the question and then write a specialized answer." \*shrug\* (FYI, not that it's any of your business: _I_ didn't downvote. Arguably I should have, because the answer was not useful (to me, at least).)

Comment: Hm. I made no assumptions, and wrote a _general_ answer. There's nothing at all about `make` in the question. Writing an answer that's only applicable to `make` would be a very specific and surprising assumption. My answer works for cases other than `make`, other than software development, other than your specific novice problem that you were having by deleting your stuff.

Comment: Rich, let it go. Getting rude will not get you upvotes or nerd cred.

Comment: Aye, mate. When you're a novice and someone tells you "here's how to catch a fish" of course that's going to look "rude" when all you wanted was a fish, a slice of lemon, and your sprig of parsley.

Comment: Kusalananda taught me how to fish. You came along and said, "Since you live in the plains, why don't you eat beef instead?"

Comment: Well you're way ahead of me. You know how to shoot. Yourself. In the foot.